# How to create and display custom characters in C kernel?

Tags: c, kernel, character, customization

I am writing a basic kernel in C and I want to create custom characters so that I can simulate drawing pixels while remaining in 25x80 text mode. Is this possible and how would I access the characters once I have created them?

I cannot use external libraries and I don't want to have to communicate with device drivers. Is there a section of memory that stores characters that can be over written or appended to?

Comment: It seems like this would depend on the display hardware.

Comment: Could you create a character in memory and use it?

Comment: You'd need to update the character generator map for the display.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that's normal for questions that show no effort to try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Or are lacking in sufficient details. A kernel programmer should understand that this is dependent on the display device driver.

Comment: Fair enough. However, I don't know how to update the character generator map.

Comment: Read the device driver documentation.

Comment: Can I modify characters without having to use a device driver?

Comment: You can write the same code that's in the device driver, but then it will be hardware-specific.

Comment: I remember back in the DOS days I have written some code to replace the character map. We also used to have special drivers for character maps for different languages

Comment: Don't. Drawing pixels in character mode is more work than drawing characters in pixel mode. In other words, create your own font, set the adapter to 640x400 mode, and draw the characters on the screen yourself.

Comment: I think the character generator functions used to be accessible via `int 10h, 11h`, which some sources are indicating is not going to work on modern computers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a section of memory that stores characters that can be over written or appended to?

No. You'll have to use BIOS interrupts (`10h`, `AH=0Ch` or `0Dh`) or VGA ports (`0x92`, `0x93`).